# Delete lines of text in JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx

I've been working with JavaFX for about two weeks now and I'm having issues with the TextArea when removing lines. I appended the following information to the TextArea, but how can I delete a specific line?

- Mary Johnson 44.33
- Laura Smith 55.12
- James Charles 23.56

How can I delete the line that has Laura Smith 55.12 and leave the other two there?
I got the first character, but I'm not sure where to go from there. Please help.

```
for (String line : reservationBox.getText().split("\n")) {
    if(line.contains(nameText.getText() + " " + priceText.getText())) {
    char firstCharacter = nameText.getText().charAt(0); //get character of the first letter of the name
    reservationBox.deleteText( ?? );
    }
}
```

Comment: You want only second line to be deleted in every case?

Comment: No. It depends on the nameText. If the nameText is James Charles, then I have to delete the third line, but I don't know how to get the first and last index of the line to let the program know which line to delete (where to start and where to end with .deleteText() )

Comment: The general idea would be to find the index range then call [`TextInputControl.deleteText(int,int)`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/11/javafx.controls/javafx/scene/control/TextInputControl.html#deleteText(int,int)) or `TextInputControl.deleteText(IndexRange)`.

Comment: That's what I'm thinking about Slaw, but I don't know how to get the index range. If I use int index1 = line.indexOf(firstCharacter); it's taking the very first character of the whole text, not where the name starts.

Comment: **Side Note**: This functionality looks better suited to a `ListView` rather than a `TextArea`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at this simple application below and apply all needed to your code:

```
/**
 *
 * @author Momir Sarac
 */
public class DeleteSpecificLineFromTextArea extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

        TextArea textArea = new TextArea();
        Button button = new Button("Get it");


        textArea.setText("Adam Smith 32\nJenny Curry 52\nTako Yoshimoto 56\n");

        String nameText = "Jenny Curry 52";

         button.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {

            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent event) {

        for (String line : textArea.getText().split("\n")) {
            if (line.contains(nameText)) {
                textArea.setText(textArea.getText().replace(line, ""));
            }
        }
        textArea.setText(textArea.getText().replaceAll("[\\\\\\r\\\\\\n]+", "\n"));
            }
        });

        StackPane root = new StackPane();
        root.getChildren().addAll(textArea,button);

        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300, 250);

        primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World!");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```

Comment: The replace method didn't cross my mind at all. I fixed what I needed in my code and it worked. Thank you.

Comment: Happy coding, @nemohack

Answer (score 1):

1. Initialize two variables that will serve as the beginning and ending indexes.
2. First index will refer to the first letter of the word that we need to delete.
3. The last index will be the sum of the beginning index and the length of the word we need minus 1.
4. Use `deleteText(startIndex, endIndex)` to delete the text.

Take a look at the code below:

```
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {

        int indexStart = 0; //initialize variables
        int indexEnd = 0;

        TextArea textArea = new TextArea();
        textArea.setText("123\nhello\nabc\ntwentyone\n"); //initialize text in box

        VBox vbox = new VBox(textArea);

        Scene scene = new Scene(vbox, 200, 100);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();

        for(String line : textArea.getText().split("\n")){
            if(line.contains("abc")) { //change this to whatever you need
                indexStart = textArea.getText().indexOf(line.charAt(0)); 
                indexEnd = indexStart + line.length()-1; 
            }

            textArea.deleteText(indexStart, indexEnd); //Delete between indexes
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Application.launch(args);
    }
```